# Can silicon dioxide melt at 20 °C?

Tags: physical-chemistry, molecular-structure, phase, pressure, melting-point

> Can $\ce{SiO2}$ melt at $\pu{20 ^\circ C}$?

I have searched the web for $\ce{SiO2}$ phase diagram, but it seems to me that almost all the graph I can find have the temperature axis where the minimum temperature is in the hundreds degrees Celsius.

Is it theoretically possible that with an high enough pressure I can melt $\ce{SiO2}$ in a temperature range like $\pu{-30 ^\circ C}$ to $\pu{50 ^\circ C}$? Or is it something theoretically simply impossible?

Comment: High pressure has tendency to cause solids to melt at higher, not lower temperatures. Ice is exception, as ice/water density ratio is exception as well.
Generally, substances increase volume when melting and high pressure  would defiinitely not to make melting easier - See [Le Chatelier's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Chatelier%27s_principle).

Comment: @Poutnik Thank you. I was reading at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_dioxide#cite_ref-16 that *Molten silica exhibits several peculiar physical characteristics that are similar to those observed in liquid water: negative temperature expansion, density maximum at temperatures ~5000 °C, and a heat capacity minimum.* Is this of some help?

Comment: but in the same article: silica density 2.648 (α-quartz), 2.196 (amorphous) g·cm−3, molten silica density 2.08 g/cm3 at 1950 °C to 2.03 g/cm3 at 2200 °C. So there is significant melting expansion.

Comment: *... have the temperature axis where the minimum temperature is in the hundreds of Celsius degree.* I guess that means that nothing interesting happens below a few hundred degrees. :-)

Comment: The diagram proposed by Alessandro Jacopson is not related to $\ce{SiO_2}$. It is the diagram of water $\ce{H_2O}$.

Comment: @Maurice Thank you, I did not add the image, see https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/revisions/135879/2

Comment: I just deleted it - even with proper context it could be misleading.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> **Question:** Can $\ce{SiO2}$ melt at $\pu{20 ^\circ C}$?

According to experimental and calculated data values, my answer is **no**. See the phase diagram of pure silica based on the experimental and calculated data given in Ref.1:

[image: Phase Diagram of silica]

Reference 1 states that:

> An internally consistent data set on the thermodynamic properties of the silica polymorphs stable up to $\pu{15 GPa}$ (α‐quartz, β‐quartz, tridymite, cristobalite, coesite, and stishovite) and the liquid phase is presented. The data set was produced through a computer‐based assessment of the properties in which the available thermochemical (calorimetric), physical (bulk modulus and thermal expansion), and solid‐state and melting transition data (including some newly determined data on the high‐pressure polymorphs cosite and stishovite) were considered. The data set can be used to calculate phase relations at pressures of $\pu{0.1 MPa}$ to $\pu{15 GPa}$ and temperatures of $300$ to $\pu{3200 K}$. The calculated phase diagram using these data agrees quite well with the phase equilibrium determinations except for the high‐temperature part of the coesitestishovite boundary. The properties of the liquid phase obtained are also in good agreement with the available data.

Keep in mind that $\pu{0.1 MPa} \approx \pu{1 atm}$. According to the phase diagram, cristobalite form is in liquid form at temperature grater than $\pu{1750 K}$ in pressure range of $\pu{0.1-0.7 MPa}$. The extrapolation of that boundary would show it would never cross $\pu{20 ^\circ C}$ point on $x$-axis without going to negative pressure. Therefore, it is impossible to have any form of $\ce{SiO2}$ in reduced or high pressusituations at room temperature or below.

**References:**

1. V. Swamy Surendra, K. Saxena, Bo Sundman, J. Zhang, “A thermodynamic assessment of silica phase diagram,” *Journal of Geophysical Research* **1994**, *99(B6)*, 11787-11794 (https://doi.org/10.1029/93JB02968).